# Keep cusor in text field and also be able to select text

Tags: jquery

Need your input please.

I have a page where I have a text field where user puts the cursor and then scans a barcode.

I need to make it so that the cursor always remains in the text field even if users clicks anywhere else.

I know this can be done using the focusout of jQuery.

But the issue is that user should still be able to select some text from the page while the cursor is still in the text input.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Use keyboard to select text.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mouseup event on the whole document. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uf8351dj/1/)

**EDIT**

if you want to copy the selected text into the clipboard, you can use `document.execCommand("copy");`
I'm not sure it is crossbrowser though.

```
$(document).on('mouseup', function() {
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $('#scanner').focus();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But when selecting the text I am not able to copy it because as soon as i release the mouse selection goes away.